# sqlalchemy, select using reverse-inclusive (not in) list of child column values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a typical Post / Tags (many tags associated with one post) relationship in flask-sqlalchemy, and I want to select posts which aren't tagged with any tag in a list I provide. First, the models I set up:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', lazy='dynamic')

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text(50))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

Something like

`db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.name.notin_(['dont','want','these']))`

fails with

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Post.tags has an attribute 'name'`

which I assume is because tags is a relationship and not a column. I had this working on another project when I was writing the actual SQL manually. This was the SQL that worked:

`SELECT * FROM $posts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM $tags WHERE name IN ('dont','want','these'))`

How would I achieve this using the sqlalchemy API?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Pretty straightforward using negated [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any):

```
query = session.query(Post).filter(~Post.tags.any(Tag.name.in_(['dont', 'want', 'these'])))
```

Comment: you sir, are a lifesaver!

Comment: in v1.4, you also need to negate the relationship subquery

Comment: What will be the query if I want all posts that don't have any tag associated with them?

Comment: @bhattraideb: `session.query(Post).filter(~Post.tags.any())`

Answer (score 18):

The [notin_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.notin_) works for me, adjusted **example**:

```
db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.notin_(['dont','want','these']))
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this one, easy:

```
users = session.query(Post).filter(not_(Post.tags.name.in_(['dont', 'want', 'these'])))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I get the same error as detailed in my original post. It's saying Post.tags doesn't have an attribute 'name'.

Answer (score 3):

I thought up a nasty solution, but it works for the time being. I'd be interested to hear if anyone comes up with a smarter method.

```
ignore_ids = [item.post_id for item in Tag.query.filter(Tag.name.in_(['dont','want','these'])).all()]
Post.query.filter(Post.id.notin_(ignore_ids))
```