# How to properly use sql alchemy's ~ or notin_ clause?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

### Update with what worked

Seems there were a few things inherently wrong with trying to do the queries in the manner I showed.

Here's what finally worked after getting inspiration from here: [Sqlalchemy in_ subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792261/sqlalchemy-in-subquery/37796647)

```
sub = db.session.query(Topic.id).outerjoin(
    highlights_topics, highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id).filter(
        highlights_topics.c.highlight_id==self.id)
        
q = db.session.query(Topic).filter(~Topic.id.in_(sub)).all()
```

### Original post

According to the documentation, the ~ should be a negation of the filter clause.

Why am I seeing these incorrect results?

there are 4 topics

```
>>> topics
[<Topic 1>, <Topic 2>, <Topic 3>, <Topic 4>]
```

I have a query that checks if a highlight is in a topic. h1 is in 2 topics.

```
>>> h1.topics.all()
[<Topic 1>, <Topic 3>]
```

and as a query using in_

```
>>> in_query = Topic.query.join(
...             highlights_topics, (highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id)
...             ).filter(
...                highlights_topics.c.highlight_id.in_([h1.id])
... 
...                ).all()
>>> in_query
[<Topic 1>, <Topic 3>]
```

Then I try the ~ or notin_ operator and am expecting `[<Topic 2>, <Topic 4>]`

But I get something else instead.

```
>>> not_in_query = Topic.query.join(
...             highlights_topics, (highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id)
...             ).filter(
...                ~highlights_topics.c.highlight_id.in_([h1.id])
... 
...                ).all() 
>>> not_in_query
[<Topic 2>, <Topic 1>, <Topic 3>, <Topic 4>]
>>>
```

as a notin_ query

```
>>> Topic.query.join(
...             highlights_topics, (highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id)
...             ).filter(
...                highlights_topics.c.highlight_id.notin_([h1.id])
... 
...                ).all()
[<Topic 2>, <Topic 1>, <Topic 3>, <Topic 4>]
>>>
```

Trying alternatively with !=

```
Topic.query.join(
            highlights_topics, (highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id)
            ).filter(
               highlights_topics.c.highlight_id != h1.id

               ).all() 

[<Topic 2>, <Topic 1>, <Topic 3>, <Topic 4>]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you use `.notin_(...)`? You only showed `~....in_(...)`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `IN` here, your list contains just one element. Why not use `highlights_topics.c.highlight_id == h1.id` here? That can then be inverted to `highlights_topics.c.highlight_id != h1.id`.

Comment: Topic.query.join(
...             highlights_topics, (highlights_topics.c.topic_id == Topic.id)
...             ).filter(
...                highlights_topics.c.highlight_id != h1.id
... 
...                ).all()
[<Topic 2>, <Topic 1>, <Topic 3>, <Topic 4>]
>>> 

Still getting the same here.

Comment: Without sample data this is guessing, but you have highlights other than h1 that have topics 1 and 3.

Comment: The first query shows all the topics. I’m also clearing the dB before these calls

Comment: Yes, but you have not shown `highlights_topics`. If for example there exists highlight h2 that has topics 1 and 3, then those are not removed by your filter.

Comment: Thanks ilija, I think that makes sense and was possibly why the filter wasn't working. 

I ended up finding a way to get the result using a subquery and the ~ operator after seeing some hints elsewhere. 

I ended up finding a working solution with