# SQL Alchemy - Querying with NOT IN Clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

The SQL Query I would like to get into SQLAlchemy form. But I couldn't write the query with sqlalchemy framework.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Availability_Schedule 
WHERE Schedule_ID NOT IN (Select Schedule_ID FROM Appointments WHERE Status = 1) 
AND Staff_ID = 1
```

**SQL Models:**

```
class AvailabilitySchedule(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Availability_Schedule'

Schedule_ID = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
Schedule_Date = Column(Date)
Slot_ID = Column(ForeignKey('Time_Slots.Slot_ID', ondelete='RESTRICT'), nullable=False, index=True)
Staff_ID = Column(ForeignKey('Hospital_Staff.Staff_ID'), nullable=False, index=True)
Room_ID = Column(ForeignKey('Rooms.Room_ID'), index=True)

Room = relationship('Room')
Time_Slot = relationship('TimeSlot')
Hospital_Staff = relationship('HospitalStaff')

class Appointment(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Appointments'

Appointment_ID = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
Schedule_ID = Column(ForeignKey('Availability_Schedule.Schedule_ID'), index=True)
Status = Column(Integer)
Patient_ID = Column(ForeignKey('Patients.Patient_ID'), index=True)
Type = Column(String(255))

Patient = relationship('Patient')
Availability_Schedule = relationship('AvailabilitySchedule')
```

SQL Alchemy:

```
schedules = AvailabilitySchedule.query.filter_by(
                                Staff_ID = doctorID,
                                Schedule_ID,not_in(Appointment.query.filter_by(Status = 1).all())
                                                         ).all()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792261/sqlalchemy-in-subquery and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206600/sqlalchemy-subquery-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Here's the two tricks you need.

1. Sqlalchemy offers this function: `.in_( ... )`
2. Negation is handled with this operator: `~`